# Change a sprite texture, with image from a sprite-sheet

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, ccsprite, sprite-sheet

This is how I create a sprite with texture form a sprite-sheet. But how do I change the sprites texture later on?

I have tried using `setTexture` but I can't get i working.

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"gameSpriteSheet.plist"];        
CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"gameSpriteSheet.png"];
[self addChild:spriteSheet];

// Add hangman graphic sprite to Scene
playerSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"playerX"];
playerSprite.position = ccp(580, 400);
[self addChild:playerSprite];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

A CCSpriteBatchNode uses a single texture. All of the sprites added to the CCSpriteBatchNode must use the same texture - that of the CCSpriteBatchNode.

I'm sure there's a different solution to the problem you're facing, give it some thought from a different angle. For example you could achieve the same effect by simply creating a new sprite.

If you're looking to change just the CCSpriteFrame of the sprite, use [setDisplayedFrame](http://learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_sprite.html#ae41c556a12991defd766670eae6ba700).

Comment: setDisplayedFrame just what I needed.. Thanks!

Comment: How about create a new sprite batch node for the new texture atlas he wants and remove the old one later?